# Can a set of vectors in $\mathbb{R}^{3}$ generate a vector space in $\mathbb{R}^{2}$?

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

I have been thinking about this question for a while, because just recently I finished my "Linear Algebra" course at the university. The question refers to any set of arbitrary vectors, and the usual $\mathbb{R}^{2}$ and $\mathbb{R}^{3}$ space.

$\textbf{My approaches}:$ What I was thinking is that for every vector in $\mathbb{R}^{3}$ to be a generator of $\mathbb{R}^{2}$, there must be a vector in R2 that can be expressed as a linear combination of $\mathbb{R}^{3}$, which is false. However, a linear transformation can generate an isomorphic space at $\mathbb{R}^{2}$.

Now the question is, is an isomorphic space at $\mathbb{R}^{2}$ equal to space $\mathbb{R}^{2}$? I do not think so.

Comment: The span of any two linearly independent vectors will be isomorphic to $\mathbb{R}^2$. I think your question is asking if $\mathbb{R}^3$ is isomorphic to a subspace of $\mathbb{R}^2$. This is impossible. If there were, then there would be three linearly independent vectors in $\mathbb{R}^2$. but...

Answer (score 1):

> > a vector in $\mathbb{R}^2$ that can be expressed as a linear combination of $\mathbb{R}^3$, which is false

This is actually true. For example, let $\mathbb{R}^2=\{(a,b,0):a,b\in\mathbb{R}\}\subset\mathbb{R}^3$. Then

$$(1,1,0)=1\times(1,0,0)+1\times(0,1,0)+0\times(0,0,1)$$

As long as the set of chosen vectors lies inside a linear subspace of dimension $2$ of $\mathbb{R}^3$, it generates a $\mathbb{R}^2$. Remark: there are many $\mathbb{R}^2$ lying inside $\mathbb{R}^3$.

If you choose the set to contain three linearly independent vectors of $\mathbb{R}^3$, as RougeSegwayUser points out, then the generated space will be $\mathbb{R}^3$.

---

Actually there are also $\mathbb{R}^2$ lying outside of $\mathbb{R}^3$, for example a tangent space of a surface living remotely somewhere on the other side of the universe, but I suspect that's not related to the question.

Comment: Strictly speaking, the space you've defined as $\mathbb{R}^2$ isn't what most people mean when the refer to $\mathbb{R}^2$. It is isomorphic to $\mathbb{R}^2$, in a way that is clear, obvious, straight-forward and almost canonical, but it is not $\mathbb{R}^2$.

Comment: Thanks. That's why I added the ending phrase. :)

Comment: Hmmm, it sounds like you are using the name $\mathbb{R}^2$ to refer to any two-dimensional linear space. The way I was taught is that $\mathbb{R}^2$ is $\{(a,b) : a,b \in \mathbb{R}\}$, and while there are many sets/spaces that are isomorphic to it, it is wrong to call them $\mathbb{R}^2$. People might refer to things like your tangent space as $\mathbb{R}^2$, or "a copy of $\mathbb{R}^2$", but we're all supposed to acknowledge that they are speaking loosely and leaving out the "isomorphic to" qualifier just for convenience.

Comment: I agree with you that I don't really understand what the OP means by $\mathbb{R}^2$, and I also agree that spaces isomorphic to $\mathbb{R}^2$ shouldn't be called/denoted/termed $\mathbb{R}^2$. But since I'm trying to answer OP's question, I think it's reasonable to adopt OP's language. Hence I typed $\mathbb{R}^2$, without knowing what space it is among all the spaces isomorphic to $\mathbb{R}^2$. Please excuse me.

Comment: No problem. I'll just say that often the question asker doesn't quite know the proper language, or doesn't understand the exact meaning of they language they are using, and so rather than repeat back their usage I think it is more useful for them if we use the exact correct language, and point out to them when the meaning is different.

Answer (score 1):

This could be considered an ambiguous question.

In a sense yes, and in a sense no.

Vectors in $\Bbb R^2$ only have $2$ coordinates; whereas vectors in $\Bbb R^3$ have $3$.  That's the sense in which it's no.

On the other hand, $\Bbb R^3$ has infinitely many copies of $\Bbb R^2$, that is, $2$-dimensional subspaces, "living" inside of it.  So in that sense yes.